# Не работает многопоточнось в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Не работает многопоточность в пайтон 3. Использую threading. Всё выполняется поочерёдно, хотя должно одновременно
вот код

```
def start_threads(threads):
    errors = 0
    for i in range(3):
        p = threading.Thread(target=Thread_Starter)
        threads_list.append(p)
    for i in threads_list:
        i.setDaemon(True)
        i.start()
```

Comment: Почитайте про GIL

Comment: Нужно уточнить, что делают потоки и как вы определяете, что все выполняется поочередно?

Answer (score 1):

> Проблема, которую решает GIL, связана с тем, что в многопоточном
> приложении сразу несколько потоков могут увеличивать или уменьшать
> значения счётчика ссылок. Это может привести к тому, что память
> очистится неправильно и удалится тот объект, на который ещё существует
> ссылка.
>
> Счётчик ссылок можно защитить, добавив блокираторы на все структуры
> данных, которые распространяются по нескольким потокам. В таком случае
> счётчик будет изменяться исключительно последовательно.
>
> Но добавление блокировки к нескольким объектам может привести к
> появлению другой проблемы — взаимоблокировки (англ. deadlocks),
> которая получается только если блокировка есть более чем на одном
> объекте. К тому же эта проблема тоже снижала бы производительность
> из-за многократной установки блокираторов.
>
> GIL — эта одиночный блокиратор самого интерпретатора Python. Он
> добавляет правило: любое выполнение байткода в Python требует
> блокировки интерпретатора. В таком случае можно исключить
> взаимоблокировку, т. к. GIL будет единственной блокировкой в
> приложении. К тому же его влияние на производительность процессора
> совсем не критично. Однако стоит помнить, что GIL уверенно делает
> любую программу однопоточной.

[источник](https://tproger.ru/translations/global-interpreter-lock-guide/)

Если вам нужно реальное параллельное исполнение кода используйте многопроцессность например с помощью модуля `multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import time
from threading import Thread
 
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
    
    def run(self):
        amount = random.randint(3, 15)
        time.sleep(amount)
        msg = "%s is running" % self.name
        print(msg)
    
def create_threads():
    for i in range(5):
        name = "Thread #%s" % (i+1)
        my_thread = MyThread(name)
        my_thread.start()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_threads()
```

С использованием multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
 
def printer(item, lock):
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        print("Thread #%s" % item)
    finally:
        lock.release()
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    for item in items:
        p = Process(target=printer, args=(item, lock))
        p.start()
```